# Progress bar not updating as expected

Tags: c#, progress-bar

The progress bar is going to 70 just fine. It's when I go to update it when the loop starts that the bar doesn't move.

```
int count = finalFiles.Length; //finalFiles in an array and it varies in size.
int current = 0;

private void uploadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{  
      uploadWorker.ReportProgress(20);

      DoSomeWork();

      uploadWorker.ReportProgress(50);

      DoMoreWork();

      uploadWorker.ReportProgress(70);

      foreach (string file in finalFiles)
      {
           current++; 
           doProcess();
           uploadWorker.ReportProgress(current / count * 30 + 70);
      }
}
```

Again, the problem is that the progress bar is not updating once it reaches 70. It just doesn't move. The form does not lock up by the way because I'm using background worker.

Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: `current` isnt being updated in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an **integer** `current`, and an **integer** `count`.  Since `count` is bigger, when you do the division it is always 0 (integer division) until `current` reaches `current`.  You should either make `count` a `double`/`decimal`, or cast one of the two to a `double`/`decimal` before doing the division.

Comment: @Testifier Example of what?  The easiest fix is to just change `count` to be of type `double` or `decimal` rather than `int`.

Comment: ahhh, let me give it a try. i'll change it to double.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `doProcess()` does, but shouldn't you increment `current` in your foreach?

Comment: my apologies, it is in the loop. i just misplaced it in the thread. i edited my OP. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some parentheses somewhere e.g.

```
 foreach (string file in finalFiles)
      {
           doProcess();
           uploadWorker.ReportProgress( ((current / count) * 30) + 70);
      }
```

OK I don't know that maths you need (sorry, I'm in the middle of something else here), but I would suggest you put parentheses in the calculation, since it looks to me like that could be an issue.

Comment: let me give it a try with the parenthesis

Comment: Oh, also fguchelaar has a point about the `current` variable not being incremented. You will need `current++` in that loop too.